# I don't understand NPM build scripts

Tags: vue.js

Modern vue projects allow you to start a webserver without pre-configuring a server.

We run:

```
npm run serve
```

which goes to a command in package.json, like:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  }
```

This confuses me!

How do I add more backend code to this?

Should I even or should I do only front-end with webpack magic? but what about a database then?

whaa?

Thanks from advance.

Answer (score 0):

Vue js is a progressive frontend framework, you need a separate application for backend developed in server side frameworks like (node js, expressjs, hapijs, sailsjs, loopbackjs, php..etc)

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  }
```

from the above scripts, if you use

```
npm run build
```

It creates a static `js`, `cs`, `html` file. You don't require any application server to run vue application. Webpack loads the Complete vue application to a static application. You can just place those files in a Web server like Nginx or using Github pages free hosting to host the site

In the development phase, it internally uses a application server on running `npm run server` to lift the application

Comment: So the build scripts are placeholder backend server without data?

Comment: build scripts (webpack configuration) are only to build your vue js application for frontend